# Switch Case In BlueJ

Tags: java, switch-statement, bluej

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(int a) {
    switch (a) {
      case 1:
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

    switch (a) {
      case 2:
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
  }
}
```

Hi, 
I want to know if it is possible for me to use Switch Case for the same variable twice, like I've done in the snippet attached.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have provided works. So long as the variable `a` is in scope, you can use it for as many `switch` statements as you like.

If you want to check for multiple values of `a` in the same `switch`, then you should use different cases. E.g.:

```
switch (a) {
  case 1:
    System.out.println("a was 1");
    break; // if we did not break, then execution would "fall-through" to the next case
  case 2:
    System.out.println("a was 2");
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("a was not 1 or 2");
}
```

Find out more about the switch statement in the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Thanks, asemahle, but I am a beginner, so forgive me for this: what do you mean by the variable being in scope?

Comment: In simplest terms: the scope of the variable is the block where it is declared, including any sub block. You cannot access a variable from outside of its scope. More [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).